# Self Hosted ServiceStack service for testing is missing metadata

Tags: servicestack

I've been following a variety of examples to get my service running, and through IIS, I now see a metadata page that lists my service.  But I also want to be able to run the service in self-hosted mode for automated tests.  I've separated the `ServiceModel` classes into a separate assembly than the `Service` classes to make it easier to distribute the ServiceModel library without my services.

Here's one example of the DTO declaration:

```cs
[Api("GET or DELETE a single folder by id.  Use POST to create a new Folder and PUT or PATCH to update it")]
[Route("/folders", "POST, PUT, PATCH")]
[Route("/folders/{Id}")]
public class Folder : IHasGuidId
{
```

And here's the start of the `FolderService`:

```cs
public class FolderService : Service
{
    public FolderResponse Get(Folder folder)
    {
```

Using this AppHost with IIS, I see my `FolderService` listed under `/metadata`.

```cs
internal class AtlasAppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AtlasAppHost() : base("API v3.0", typeof(FolderService).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.Adapter = new StructureMapContainerAdapter();
        AtlasInit(Config);
    }

    internal void AtlasInit(EndpointHostConfig config)
    {
        JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = true;
        JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
        JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
        config.EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove(Feature.Jsv | Feature.Soap | Feature.Csv);
    }
}
```

But, with the `IntegrationTestBase` below, when I pause the debugger, I don't see my `FolderService` under `/metadata`, and the requests always return `NotFound`

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class ApiIntegrationTestBase
{
    private TestAppHost _appHost;
    protected const string TestServiceUrl = "http://localhost:9755/";

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        _appHost = new TestAppHost();
        _appHost.Init();
        _appHost.Start(TestServiceUrl);
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TestFixtureTearDown()
    {
        _appHost.Dispose();
    }

    public class TestAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
    {
        public TestAppHost()
            : base("Test App Host", typeof(FolderService).Assembly)
        {
        }

        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            var atlasAppHost = new AtlasAppHost();
            atlasAppHost.Configure(container);
            atlasAppHost.AtlasInit(Config);
            Routes.AddFromAssembly(typeof (FolderService).Assembly);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in order to get my `FolderService` to appear in the self hosted tests assembly?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder, when you self host, do you have to have ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory in your config file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor of your AppHosts you're pointing to 2 different assemblies:

```
public AtlasAppHost() : base("API v3.0", typeof(FolderService).Assembly) {}
```

and

```
public TestAppHost() : base("Test App Host", typeof(AtlasAppHost).Assembly) {}
```

By default, only `IService`'s that exist in these assemblies are registered and auto-wired.

Note: you can provide multiple assemblies in the base AppHost constructor, see the wiki on [Modularizing Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Modularizing-services) for more info.

Comment: Nice catch.  But those classes actually are in the same assembly.